# Round to nearest 5 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a Money column in my SQL Server 2008 table. In my below query how can I round it to nearest 5$

```
select FineAmount from tickets
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you define "nearest"? I.e., what result do you want for values of 0, 1, 2.5, and 4 go? Rounding money can mean different things depending on the use case.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
select round(FineAmount*2,-1)/2 from tickets
```

or to put nicholaides suggestion in sql

```
select round(FineAmount/5,0)*5 from tickets
```

The example assumes that FineAmount is of type money.
The second approach is probably better as the first one works with the limit of maximum_value_of_money_type/2

More on [ROUND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

Comment: The only note I'd add to this is make sure that it divides the 5 as a decimal, not an integer. you can either wrap it in a convert/cast, or add a 0 to it, to make sure it works correctly.

       e.g. select round(FineAmount/5.0,0)*5 from tickets

Answer (score 25):

A general math solution:

Divide by 5, round to the nearest integer, then multiply by 5.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to truncate (round-down) to a grouping of 5 use the modulo function; in Microsoft SQL Server this is `%`

ie: `field1` - (`field1` % 5)

If you had field1 == 3, then the calc would be:

3 - (3 % 5) = 0

if it were 13:

13 - (13 % 5) = 10

Simply add 5 if you want to round up

See also ['MOD' is not a recognized built-in function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310661/mod-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name)

Comment: Note that "Operand data type float is invalid for modulo operator"

Comment: But 10 rounding up is 10-(10%5)+5 = 15 but should be 10.

Answer (score 1):

My first solution was

```
create function dbo.udf_RoundToNearest(@x int, @to int)
returns int
with schemabinding as begin
return @to * convert(int, round(convert(float, @x) / convert(float, @to), 0))
end
```

This works, but is considered by MSSQL as 'imprecise' since it uses floating point numbers internally.  That stops it being used in indexed views.  You can instead do the job only with integer arithmetic:

```
create function dbo.udf_RoundToNearest(@x int, @to int)
returns int
with schemabinding as begin

declare @m int
set @m = abs(@x) % abs(@to)

declare @trunc int
set @trunc = abs(@x) - @m

declare @r int
set @r = case when @m * 2 >= abs(@to) then @trunc + abs(@to) else @trunc end

return case when @x < 0 then -@r else @r end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Round to next greater 5

```
(CAST(@Amount/5 AS INT) + IIF(CAST(ROUND(@Amount,0) AS INT) % 5>1,1,0))*5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Amount DECIMAL(18,3) ; SET @Amount = 7818.32

SELECT(Round((@Amount-CAST(@Amount AS INT))*100 /5,0)*5 /100) 
      + CAST( @Amount AS INT)
```

-- you'll get **7818.30**

Answer (score -10):

Use ROUND function

```
    SELECT  ROUND(FineAmount,5)
    FROM    tickets
```

Comment: The integer value in the `ROUND` overload is to indicate decimal precision, not multiple to round by.