# 'MOD' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, modulo

I wanted to use `MOD` function in `SQL Server 2008R2` and followed this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634767(v=sql.105).aspx)  but still got the message:

> 'MOD' is not a recognized built-in function name.

```
DECLARE @m INT
SET @m = MOD(321,11)
SELECT @m
```

Error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
>   'MOD' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Why I can't use this function from the link above?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The `MOD` keyword only exists in the `DAX` language (tabular dimensional queries), not `TSQL`

Use  `%` instead.

Ref: [Modulo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Life saving ans. thnx

Comment: `MOD` also works in [__Informix__](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Informix) syntax...  For all those back in the 1990s!

Comment: It's kind of upsetting that SQL Server is not ANSI compliant, though. I want to be able to write a SQL query that will work everywhere. Oracle uses MOD(), MySQL uses MOD() and %, Microsoft Uses %. Ridiculous.

Answer (score 8):

In TSQL, the modulo is done with a percent sign.

SELECT 38 % 5 would give you the modulo 3

Answer (score 2):

for your exact sample, it should be like this.

```
DECLARE @m INT
SET @m = 321%11
SELECT @m
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using the `%` operator.

**i.e.**

```
SELECT 50 % 5
```

Answer (score -5):

If using JDBC driver you may use function escape sequence like this:

```
select {fn MOD(5, 2)}
#Result 1

select  mod(5, 2)
#SQL Error [195] [S00010]: 'mod' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Comment: is not the answer of question , MOD Returns the remainder after a number is divided by a divisor. The result always has the same sign as the divisor.