# What does '%' mean in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I inherited some SQL codes and one part of the codes goes like:

```
    CASE WHEN 
    (CAST(CAST(b.xx AS numeric(11, 6)) 
            * CAST(a.ratio AS numeric(11, 6)) AS decimal(10, 0)) % a.mktcoupons =0) 
       THEN CAST((CAST(b.xx AS numeric(11, 6)) * 
            CAST(a.ratio AS numeric(11, 6))) / a.mktcoupons AS decimal(10, 0)) 
    ELSE 
    CAST(( CAST(b.xx AS numeric(11, 6)) 
            * CAST(a.ratio AS numeric(11, 6))) / a.mktcoupons AS decimal(10, 0)) 
    + (CAST(CAST(b.xx AS numeric(11, 6)) 
        * CAST(a.ratio AS numeric(11, 6)) AS decimal(10, 0)) % a.mktcoupons) 
    END AS yy
```

I understand the general expression of 'case when A then B else C end' . However, I am having a hard time figuring out what does '%' mean? I checked 'mktcoupons' and there is no zero value in 'mktcoupon'. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: That is the `modulo` operation.

Comment: It's called the modulo operation. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) you can find more details. It's a basic programming operator that returns the remainder after a division.

Comment: ... sometimes called the "remainder" operator - it gives the remainder after performing a division operation.

Comment: Why are these comments and not answers?

Comment: @BrianBall Because one line answers should not be answers, but comments.

Comment: but if you add a Link it is two lines ;)

Comment: @swe Yes, but these kinds of answers are not encouraged, although they are right. Generally a question like this could have been resolved by a web-search rather than a post on `SO`. And I can't give any more details, I used to do this as well, one line answers, but the questions got closed and moderators gave this reason for closing.

Comment: you are absolutely right with that point. But then we should put the question on hold... There are hundreds of silly/easy to answer questions around here each day...

Comment: Thanks everybody who contributed to the answers! I actually did send quite some time google around and tried different expressions like '%' in SQL or "%" in SQL. I thought it would be an easy kill, but surprisingly none of the answers popped up mention modulo division. That was why I turn to stackoverflow...Thanks again! :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008R2: 'MOD' is not a recognized built-in function name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310661/sql-server-2008r2-mod-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is a modulo division.
see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms190279.aspx

Comment: Thanks the link is very helpful. The example 'SELECT 38 / 5 AS Integer, 38 % 5 AS Remainder' says it all!!

Answer (score 0):

If its in a mathematical operation its most likely [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

If its used in a string it basically means "any number of any character".